# IDE can't track my code after I use the go module

Tags: go, visual-studio-code

1、After repeated debugging, I still can't solve it. I reinstalled :go13, vscode

2、vim ~/.bash_profile 
export GO111MODULE=auto
export GOPROXY=https://goproxy.io

source  ~/.bash_profile

3、A series of tools such as golint godef gocode have been reinstalled.But still can't track the function in the code，

I spent 3 hours trying to fix it. I don't know what to do, please help me.
thank you very much❤️❤️❤️

[image]
This is my env information

[image]

As you can see in the picture, no errors are indicated, how should I set it up?

Comment: The IDE does not recognize the import package, the package is placed in pkg / mod, but the IDE looks for it under src /.

Comment: Exact same setup works for me under macOS, except for the usage of goproxy.io. Have you tried without?

Comment: Furthermore, you might want to use goproxy‘s instructions for >= Go 1.13: `$ go env -w GOPROXY=https://goproxy.io,direct`

Comment: Thank you for helping me, I edited the question, can you help me analyze it?@Markus W Mahlberg

Comment: You should reset your environment and _follow the instructions_ for Go >= 1.13 on goproxy.io.

Comment: I woke up and got a clear idea. I suddenly thought that there was a problem with the vscode settings. When I cleared the vscode custom settings, the prompts came out again. Thank you for helping me yesterday.

Comment: 再次感谢您帮助我，vscode重新提示了，并且import找到了mod的安装包，感谢你，友善的陌生人@Markus W Mahlberg

Comment: Seriously, Chinese(?) is understood by few outside of China. ;)

Comment: Haha, I forgot to translate. The Q&amp;A environment in China is terrible. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

1、我清空了vscode的自定义设置（解决了vscode不提示问题）
2、go mod init 生成了mod文件（解决了import找不到安装包的红线报告）

感谢Markus W Mahlberg，因为是他提醒了我。

Comment: Again - Chinese? ;)